# Prevent columns from being renamed when using by_row(., collate = "col")

Tags: r, purrr

**Code**

```
library(purrrlyr)
mtcars[1:2, 1:2] %>% 
    by_row(function(x) 
               as.data.frame(setNames(as.list(1:5), LETTERS[1:5])), 
           .collate = "cols")
# # tibble [2 x 7]
#     mpg   cyl    A1    B1    C1    D1    E1
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1    21     6     1     2     3     4     5
# 2    21     6     1     2     3     4     5
```

**Question**

Is there a way how I can avoid that `by_row` "decorates" the names of my data frame by adding `1` to the column names?

**Expecetd Outcome**

```
# # tibble [2 x 7]
#     mpg   cyl     A     B     C     D     E
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1    21     6     1     2     3     4     5
# 2    21     6     1     2     3     4     5
```

Comment: Ah difficult, one way would replacing cols with `.collate = "rows"`, but this adds the `.row` col

Comment: That would do the trick. Easier to remove the `row` col. +1. Would you bother to formulate this as an answer and I will happily accept this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, this method produces the desired columns but adds the `.row` column.

```
library(purrrlyr)
mtcars[1:2, 1:2] %>% 
    by_row(function(x) 
               as.data.frame(setNames(as.list(1:5), LETTERS[1:5])), 
           .collate = "rows")

 #       mpg   cyl  .row     A     B     C     D     E
 #     <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 #   1    21     6     1     1     2     3     4     5
 #   2    21     6     2     1     2     3     4     5
```